# how can i change the X and Y coordinate of my thumbs to take the X and Y on the images inside?

Tags: c#, xaml, thumbnails

I want my thumbs to take the x and y of its child.
How can i do this?
This is my code of 1 of the thumbs:

```
<Thumb x:Name="thumb37"  Canvas.ZIndex="99" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" >
            <Thumb.Template >
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="images/table1.jpg" Name="t5" Margin="965,152,111,709"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>
```

Comment: What if you remove the `Margin` part?

Comment: Why is there a `Margin` on the child? Also, what is this in? WPF, UWP, SL, etc? Are you just trying to customize a scrollbar or something?

Comment: im trying to make a dynamic floorplan , its WPF